# Валидация на сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть web-приложение на ASP.NET MVC с трехслойной архитектурой.При добавлении если объект не прошел валидацию в бизнес-логике, то список ошибок в каком виде лучше отправлять?

Comment: а кому вы ошибки, и для каких целей отправлять собираетесь?

Comment: если вам нужно ошибки дебажить, то можно через javascript: Console.log, если требуется отладка кода, то сначала используйте юнит тестирование и интеграционное тестирование, если вы хотите ловить, очень редкие ошибки, которые просто не возможно выловить при тестировании, используйте NLog, в общем вопрос, тебует разъяснения, его суть не понятна, по крайней мере для меня.

Comment: А бизнес логика, ваша имеет тестирование?

Comment: Бизнес логика полностью покрыта юнит-тестами

Comment: Отправить на уровень PL чтобы вывести пользователю, что не так он сделал

Comment: Вопрос в том, что в каком виде лучше вернуть ошибки. строковым представлением или с помощью кодов ошибок?

Comment: так задайте вопрос правильно. На мой взгляд, правильнее выводить пользователю сообщение, о том что он не правильно сделал.

Comment: Если строки то стоит ли сделать шаблоны для описания.? Что-то типа этого: У класса Error будет два поля. Одно типа перечисления. Enum из полей которые валидируются. (Enum Fields { Name, Year и тд  }). А второе строка которая формируется  {Fields.Name}  + константа из отдельной сборки, где строки для шаблонов ошибок. К примеру если имя не прошло валидацию, то  {Fields.Name}  + Required. И В итоге на PL передастся: Name обязательно для заполнения

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос философский. Правильный ответ: "Кому как удобнее". 
На мой взгляд приятнее будет пробрасывать текст, так как значение кода ошибки может измениться, а никто не будет отслеживать Ваши изменения (в случае, если к Вашему API будут цепляться другие сервисы). Так же не очень принято размазывать логику, а в случае кодов именно так и будет (фронт помимо отрисовки будет знать стороннюю информацию вроде значения + искать где что будет сложнее).

Comment: А вообще правильный подход возвращать список ошибок где к каждому полю привязано описание ошибки. Может быть есть оптимальней вариант? Я на production только месяц.

Comment: Никогда не видел списка ошибок. Обычно валидатор останавливает работу на первой же ошибке валидации (это связано с тем, что сервер достаточно узкое место, поэтому если уже понятно, что косяк - будьте добры сами посмотрите и переделайте). Но в целом это реализуемо.
Как вариант ещё делать некоторую валидацию на то, что присылает пользователь на фронте. Например, проверять, что при отправке имени не отправляют "123".

Comment: Правда, валидация на фронте не отменяет необходимость делать валидацию на бэке, так как кто-то может просто слать вам запросы, без использования фронта. Но тем не менее, обычно это снижает нагрузку на сервер.